# Output mysql query result in a php variable

Tags: php, sql

I have this variable (`$sql`) in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, dob)),'%y Years %m Months %d Days') AS age WHERE id=$row[id]";
```

How to output the produced data as a *PHP variable*?

The query is taking the date of birth from my table and calculating the age from today's date.

How to echo the age in PHP?

Comment: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) this should help you out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass", "database_name"); //your connection
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, dob)),'%y Years %m Months %d Days') AS age FROM table_name WHERE id=".$row['id'];    
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $result['age'];
```

Don't forget to replace table_name.

Comment: Sorry misunderstand

Answer (score 0):

try this code

i see your code you miss table name

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, dob)),'%y Years %m Months %d Days') AS age WHERE id=$row[id]";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($query_data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    $age= $query_data[0];
    print $age;
```

Comment: You don't have a table name and `FROM` either? Also the PHP variable `$row[id]` is wrong.. should be `" . $row['id']`. `mysql_` functions are not supported anymore

Comment: yups i also miss those thing which you mention

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, dob)),'%y Years %m Months %d Days') AS age WHERE id=$row[id]";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "age: " . $row["age"]. "<br>";}
} 
else {
echo "No result!";
}
```

You can reference from http://www.w3schools.com